# $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}|t-f(t)|\,\mathrm dt$. How to deal with mod?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, contest-math

Let $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function which satisfies $$
\forall \ x\in \Bbb R,\ f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}|t-f(t)|\,\mathrm dt,
$$
then how do we prove that the function $f$ is monotonic, onto and an odd function.

I'm unable to deal with the modulus function. Is there anyway to remove the mod and deal with a linear differential equation. If we do not remove the mod, there is also the question of whether RHS is differentiable or not? If it is, then we could write $f'(x)=|x-f(x)|$ which would prove that f is monotonous and onto, but we still have a problem with odd. How to deal with mod in differential equations?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should probably avoid using $x$ as your integration variable

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: You also have $f(0)=0$. Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$.

Comment: As $f$ is supposed to be differentiable, it is continuous. Hence the RHS of the equality is differentiable and $f$ satisfies the IVP $f^\prime(x)=\lvert x -f(x)\rvert$ with $f(0)=0$. According to Picard Lindelöf theorem it has a unique solution around $0$. As the odd function $f(-x)=-f(x)$ satisfies the integral equation, the solution is odd. It is obviously increasing. It remains to prove that the solution is defined on all the reals, as from there the fact that is is onto can be obtained in a straight way from the differential equation.

Comment: Nice problem 1+. A simple explicit solution is $f(x) = x+e^{-x}-1$ for $x \gt 0$ and $f(x \lt 0) = - f(-x)=x-e^x+1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's extend the question and prove the following things:

1. The existence around zero of a continuously differentiable solution. *This is supposed in the question.*
2. That the solution **is defined on $\mathbb R$.** *This is also supposed in the question.*
3. That $f$ is increasing.
4. That $f$ is onto.
5. That $f$ is odd.

**Point 1**

The IVP problem $f^\prime(x)=\lvert x - f(x) \rvert$, $f(0)=0$ has a unique solution around $0$ according to [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) as the map $(x,y) \mapsto \lvert x - y \rvert$ is locally Lipschitz in $y$. This solution is obviously a solution to the problem of the question
$$f(x) = \int_0^x \lvert t - f(t) \rvert dt $$ in a neighborhood of zero.

**Point 3**

Obvious.

**Point 2**

For $x \gt 0$, if the solution of the IVP was only defined in an interval $[0,a)$, we would have $\lim\limits_{x \to a } f(x) = \infty$. Hence it would exist $ 0 \lt b \lt a$ such that $f^\prime(x) = f(x) - x$ for $x \gt b$. We get a contradiction as the solution to this differential equation is bounded in $[0,a]$. **We obtain the desired conclusion that the solution is defined in $\mathbb  R$.**

**Point 5**

A direct consequence of the unicity of Picard–Lindelöf theorem, as the function defined by $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for $x \gt 0$ is solution of the IVP.

**Point 4**

If $f$ wasn't onto, as it is increasing, it would be bounded. Hence for $x$ large enough, we would have $f^\prime(x) = x - f(x)$. A contradiction as a solution to this differential equation, is defined on $\mathbb R$ and not bounded.

**Additional note**

In fact, the equation can be solved. As $f(0)=0$ for a solution around zero of the IVP, we have $f^\prime(0)=0$. Therefore $x \gt f(x)$ in an interval $I=[0,a)$ with $a \gt 0$. In $I$, the IVP is $f^\prime(x)=x-f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$. The solution in this interval is

$$f(x)=e^{-x}+x-1.$$

Which in fact is a solution of the IVP for $x \ge 0$.

Finally the unique solution of the integral equation is the odd map defined by $f(x)=e^{-x}+x-1$ for $x \ge 0$.